# Sharing a serial port between two processes

Tags: linux, serial

As it is not possible to directly share a serial port between two processes using Linux, I am looking for another way to achieve this, I have heard about socat but could not find a concrete example of how to realize the following:

Split one physical serial port (/dev/ttyUSB0) into two virtual ports, one for reading and one for writing, as one process only needs to send data, and one only needs to receive data.

I can not modify the sending application unfortunately.

Comment: "As it is not possible to directly share a serial port between two processes" Why do you think so?

Comment: multiple sources (such as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8745948/how-can-you-access-a-serial-port-from-two-different-processes-python) confirm this , but if it's possible anyway, please tell me ;)

Comment: did you note the edit to the question you referred: "Edit -- This needs to work on Windows, but Mac and Linux would also be nice." The answer was given for the Windows case. In linux it always was a problem to get exclusive access to the serial ports as the only way to restrict unwanted interferention is the user/group access rights, so the convention had been established with time how to tell other processes not to open the serial port device when some process is willing to 'own' it. So you may open it from different processes provided the processes uids or gids has rw access on it

Comment: So you are simply stating that I can in fact access a serial device from multiple processes? If so, please post it as an answer, I will test it somewhere after the weekend probably, but then you will get your mark ;)

Comment: Yes. That's correct

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In linux it always was a problem to get exclusive access to the serial ports as the only way to restrict unwanted interferention is the user/group access rights.

With time the convention had been established how to tell the other processes not to open the serial port device when some process is willing to 'own' it: the process that is going to open the serial (parallel) port first check for lock file in the `/tmp` directory (other standards may use `/var/lock` directory), for example /tmp/LCK..ttyS0 in case of the ttyS0 device and writes its `PID` into that file. Then it reads it back and if the `PID` matches then the process took the ownership of the port. After the port is not needed any more the lock file is deleted by the process.

Thus you may open it from different processes provided these processes uids or gids has rw access on the device

Comment: I have /dev/ttyACM0 (an usb serial port) accessed by one proces that writes data to the port. I have another process (screen /dev/ttyACM0 9600) that should read data from the port. Nothing is being printed to the screen however.

Comment: Must have had something to do with screen wanting to use flow control I suppose, when using a simple cat /dev/ttyACM0 everything works fine!

Comment: did you see this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/17983721/309483